# In TypeScript, what is the proper config to make module alias work when building the dist folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I was experimenting on module alias for typescript and it works during `dev`, but when I try to build it I always get cannot find module because it is pointing to `src` file even on build.

I tried replacing `dist` to `moduleAliases` in `package.json`. It compiled, however, when I run `yarn run dev`, it is using the `dist` folder source code instead of my `src`. I also tried introducing `tsconfig-paths` to my `dev` e.g `"dev": "NODE_ENV=development ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts",` but the system is still reading the `moduleAliases`. Maybe someone here have encountered similar issue while doing module paths.

Here is my project structure:

```
|-project
|---src
|-------index.ts  // (where I put require('module-alias/register');)
|-------app (business logic) // where I start using modules e.g import config from '@config/index.config';
|-----------index.ts
|-----------routes
|-------config
|---dist
|---node_modules
|---.env
|---.eslintrc
|---package.json
|---tsconfig.json
|---yarn.lock
```

Snippet of my `package.json`

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
"scripts": {
  "dev": "NODE_ENV=development ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly ./src/index.ts",
  "prod": "yarn run build && node -r ./dist/index.js",
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production yarn run build-ts",
  "build-ts": "tsc -p .",
},  
"_moduleAliases": {
  "@config": "./src/config",
  "@routes": "./src/app/routes",
},
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@config/*": ["config/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["app/routes/*"],
    },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true 
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

My `.eslintrc` (not sure if it matters or relevant to this problem)

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb-typescript/base"],
  "rules": {
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "babel-module": {}
    }
  }
}
```

How I use it

```
import config from '@config/index.config';
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question has already been resolved in an issue I opened at github https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias/issues/74#issuecomment-535379630 :)